# Regular Expression for Highlighting Indented Bullets in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to write some matching rules in a Vim syntax file to highlight indented bullets. My problem is that the syntax highlighting uses a background color, so I would like to match *only* the bullet character and not the preceding whitespace.

How can I say "match \d., +, -, and * only if preceded by ^\s\{0,1} (but **do not** match the whitespace)"

With the following matching rules,

```
syn match notesBullet /^\s*\*/
hi def link notesBullet String 
syn match notesNumber /^\s*\d*\./
hi def link notesNumber String
syn match notesMinus /^\s*\-/
hi def link notesMinus Todo 
syn match notesPlus /^\s*+/
hi def link notesPlus Plus
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Is there some way to say "if preceded by, but not including" in Vim regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the lookarounds mentioned by Alex, Vim patterns also have the concept of "match start" and "match end" which are denoted by `\zs` and `\ze`, respectively.  Vim will only match when the whole pattern is there, but will exclude everything before `\zs` and\or after `\ze` (you don't have to specify both) from the match.

So in your case, you can add `\zs` after your whitespace pattern and before the bullet/number pattern. For example: `/^\s*\zs\d*\./`

Comment: Thank Jay, exactly what I needed. I think I could have done it with lookarounds, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to say "if preceded
>   by" in Vim regex?

Yep, it's called a "zero-width" match, `\@<=` (it's known as a "look-behind" in the RE sublanguage of Perl and Python).  See [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width) for all details.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Alex. However, /\(\s*\)\@=\*/ matches every '*' and /^\(\s*\)\@=\*/ or /\(^\s*\)\@=\*/ don't match indented '*'. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `\s*` means "zero or more spaces" so I'd _expect_ it to match anything.  What about `\s+` (meaning "one or more") instead?

Comment: Look-behind is `\@<=`, not `\@=` which is look-ahead. Did the parser eat `<`?

Comment: @ZyX, not the parser's fault but mine -- tx for the spotting, +1!